# JqGrid: sorting of local data

Tags: jqgrid

I have some problem with local data sorting in this example. Sorting doesn't work and I don't know reason of it. Could you explain problem in my code?

```
<table id="list" ></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData =  [
                        { id: "1",  cell: ["1", "test"] },
                        { id: "2",  cell: ["2", "test2"] },
                        { id: "3",  cell: ["3", "test3"] },
                        { id: "4",  cell: ["4", "test4"] }
    ];
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    data: myData,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['MyId','Client'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'MyId', index: 'MyId', width: 100, align: 'left' ,  sortable: true},
               { name: 'Client', index: 'Client', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: true }],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30,100],
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'Id',
    localReader: {repeatitems: true},          
    viewrecords: true,
    sortable: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: "Tests",
    loadonce: true
});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

</script>
```

P.S. Sorting also doesn't work in this demo with local data. http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalReader.htm

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that I can't sort values in my grid using jqgrid sorting. You may click on header of 'client' column in demo [link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalReader.htm) and see that sorting doesn't change order of element.

Comment: And sorting means jqgrid local sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: jqGrid have bug in usage `datatype: "local"` with `data` parameter in `localReader: {repeatitems: true}` format.

There are many ways to fix the bug. One from the most easy one seems me to replace [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1551-L1555)

```js
if(locdata || ts.p.treeGrid===true) {
    rd[locid] = $.jgrid.stripPref(ts.p.idPrefix, idr);
    ts.p.data.push(rd);
    ts.p._index[rd[locid]] = ts.p.data.length-1;
}
```

with the following

```js
if(locdata || ts.p.treeGrid===true) {
    rd[locid] = $.jgrid.stripPref(ts.p.idPrefix, idr);
    ts.p.data.push(rd);
    ts.p._index[rd[locid]] = ts.p.data.length-1;
} else if (ts.p.datatype === "local" && dReader.repeatitems) {
    var idStripted = $.jgrid.stripPref(ts.p.idPrefix, idr),
        iData = ts.p._index[idStripted];
    if (iData !== undefined && ts.p.data != null && ts.p.data[iData] != null) {
        $.extend(true, ts.p.data[iData], rd);
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalReader1.htm) uses [the fixed code](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-localReaderRepeatitemsTrue.js) and it works correctly now. I will post later the corresponding pull request with suggested fix to trirand.

**UPDATED**: I posted better implementation of the fix in [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/621).
**UPDATED 2:** My pull request is already [merged](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/9f03534b4cfe60ae682874e0f6465778f813d1f1) to [the main code of jqGrid on the github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). You can do the same changes on `jquery.jqGrid.srs.js`, download the modified file from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-localReader.js). In any way the next version of jqGrid (version higher as 4.6.0) will contains the fix of described problem.

Comment: Thank you for solution of my problem. Could you suggest other fix of this bug without changing of source code of library? I think I should not change source code of my local copy of jqgrid library, because other people who will change my code may change source of jqgrid and in result get this bug again.

Comment: @Aracturat: You are welcome! I'll post the bug fix to trirand and I think it will be included in the next version of jqGrid. So the suggested changing of the code of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` is really safe. If you do prefer to use the original code of jqGrid then you should use just the default `repeatitems: false` format of `myData`: `var myData = [{id:"1", MyId:"1", Client:"test"}, ...];` You should of cause remove `localReader` option.

Comment: @Aracturat: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @Aracturat: See **UPDATED 2** part of my answer.