# jqGrid - sorting won't work when datatype:local (jsFiddle included)

Tags: arrays, sorting, types, jqgrid, local

I couldn't find any solution.
I want to load my data from a local array. When I use the same settings in a different grid with datatype:json, from server, everything works fine.

But here I need a local array, I use data option. array is in format:

```
[[x,y,z], ...]
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/7osga648/

CODE:

```
$("#datagrid1").jqGrid({
        datatype:'local',height:350,width:400,gridview:true,rownumbers:true,rowNum:1000,viewrecords:true,
        colNames:["time","col1","col2"],
        colModel:[
       {name:'time',width:150,resizable:false,sorttype:'date',datefmt:"d/m/Y H:i:s"},

        {name:'f1',width:100,resizable:false,sorttype:'number'},
        {name:'f2',width:100,resizable:false,sorttype:'number'}],
        data:[["03/10/2014 20:46:27","60.8","2.5"],["03/10/2014 21:01:39","58.3","0.1"],["03/10/2014 21:16:51","61.3","3.4"],["03/10/2014 21:32:05","58.9","0.6"],["03/10/2014 21:47:18","58.7","0.8"],["03/10/2014 22:02:32","58.2","0.0"],["03/10/2014 22:17:45","61.9","3.8"],["03/10/2014 22:32:58","58.4","0.1"],["03/10/2014 22:48:11","60.0","2.1"],["03/10/2014 23:03:22","61.2","3.4"],["03/10/2014 23:18:34","62.0","3.8"],["03/10/2014 23:33:47","58.6","0.2"],["03/10/2014 23:49:00","58.4","0.2"],["04/10/2014 00:04:14","58.1","0.2"],["04/10/2014 00:19:28","58.1","0.2"],["04/10/2014 00:34:40","61.8","3.9"],["04/10/2014 00:49:51","58.9","0.6"],["04/10/2014 01:05:03","58.2","0.1"],["04/10/2014 01:20:16","61.2","3.4"],["04/10/2014 01:35:28","59.2","0.9"],["04/10/2014 01:50:40","58.4","0.1"],["04/10/2014 02:00:04","0","0"],["04/10/2014 02:05:52","61.8","3.7"],["04/10/2014 02:21:04","62.9","3.7"],["04/10/2014 02:36:15","63.1","3.5"],["04/10/2014 02:51:27","63.7","3.5"],["04/10/2014 03:06:40","60.1","0.0"],["04/10/2014 03:21:53","63.1","3.1"]],
        localReader:{repeatitems:true,cell:""},
        caption:"sorting not working. click on col header"
    });
```

Try to click on column header, and see that nothing is happening.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted already the bug fix [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/621). The modified demo "jsfiddle.net/7osga648/4/" uses directly the new features. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24912577/315935) for additional information.

Comment: wow. Couldn't guess it would be a bug. I mean, it does sound pretty simple to find out such a bug (local data). I thought that my "localReader" setting is wrong. So what should I do? Should I replace the lines in the source code, as you wrote, and than minify the whole code?  I prefer not to download your fixed version since I've created a custom build (the full library is too big for me, and I don't need treegrid for example).  And BTW, I don't understand all the changes you done in the fiddle. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user3599803: The simplest workaround - you should change format of input data. Instead of `["03/10/2014 20:46:27","60.8","2.5"]` you should use `{time: "03/10/2014 20:46:27", f1: "60.8", f2: "2.5"}`. You should of cause remove `localReader` option. The modified demo just uses `normalizeData` function, which append every item with **named properties** (`time`, `f1`, `f2`) based on `colModel`. So you can either change format of input data or follow my demo which removes `data` parameter and which use `onInitGrid` which do set `data` and calls `normalizeData` (`orderedCols` and `reader`).

Comment: Well, it is easier for me than messing with the minified code. Very much thanks to you.